# How to create nested JSON objects in FSharp

Tags: json, f#

What is the best and readable solution for creating complex nexted JSON objects in F#? Something like the following JavaScript code:

```
{
   data: {
      user: {
        first_name:'myFirstName',
        last_name:'myLastName',
        address: {
           street: 'myStreet'
        }
      },
      type: 'user'
   }
}
```

Comment: Type providers might be of use? See http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html for details.

Comment: If rather than reading JSON you want to create JSON, basically serializing your types, then Newtonsoft, Chiron, fhsarplu, etc. But in the end it's just text manipulation. You should try to give more context, e.g. what's your input and expected output.

Comment: You can create F# Record Types that represent the same structure as your JSON objects.  Marking them with the CLIMutable attribute should make them Serializable.  You can then use a library like Netwonsoft to serialize the record types to JSON, just make sure to set ContractResolver in the SerializerSettings to an instance of the Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver, or you won't get the correct field names in your JSON.

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach Newtonsoft doesn’t even require CLIMutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JsonValue from FSharp.Data I like this one:

```
let data = 
    ( FSharp.Data.JsonValue.Record [|
        "event", FSharp.Data.JsonValue.String eventName; 
        "properties", FSharp.Data.JsonValue.Record 
            (Array.append [| 
                "token", FSharp.Data.JsonValue.String token;
                "distinct_id", FSharp.Data.JsonValue.String (distinctId())
            |] param)
    |])
```

Answer (score 0):

Chiron is a nice JSON Library https://github.com/xyncro/chiron

```
Json.parse """
  {
    "foo": [ { "bar": 1 }, { "bar": 2 }, { "bar": "fizz" } ],
    "test": { "one":3.5, "two":null, "three":false }
  }
"""
```

` results into ->

```
Object
  (map
     [("foo",
       Array
         [Object (map [("bar", Number 1M)]); Object (map [("bar", Number 2M)]);
          Object (map [("bar", String "fizz")])]);
      ("test",
       Object
         (map [("one", Number 3.5M); ("three", Bool false); ("two", Null null)]))])
```

Can also be used with types.

https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2015/12-15-chiron-taming-types-in-the-wild/index.html

https://neoeinstein.github.io/blog/2015/12-13-chiron-json-ducks-monads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To serialize any F# object or list of objects/records/unions, etc, I use this code (you might need to fill/correct some details, as I don't have the complete file available at the moment):

```
open System.IO

type ResultInfo = { Result: string; ErrorMsg: string } // or use built-in Result type instead

// To install the Json.NET library, enter "Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json" in the Tools...NuGet Package Manager...Package Manager Console.
// let str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(...) throws an OutOfMemoryException for large collections, so use a StreamWriter instead.
let jsonSerializeToFile obj file =
    try
        (new FileInfo(file)).Directory.Create()
        use writer = File.CreateText(file)
        let ser =  new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
        ser.Formatting <- Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
        ser.Serialize(writer, obj)
        { Result = "ok"; ErrorMsg = None } // maybe return the length of the serialized string??
    with
        | ex -> { Result = "error"; ErrorMsg = Some <| ex.ToString() }
```